# Groovy Scripts to Stored image/png content type as .png in SOAP UI

Tags: java, api, groovy, soapui

I am hitting API which is returning me the response like this

```
<data contentType="image/png;charset=UTF-8" contentLength="57789">Rescre....</data>
```

I want to store the response as an image file (.png) using groovy script on soap UI.

I tried something like that :-

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
String dirName="C:\\";

def httpResponse = context.testCase.testSteps["GetPNG"].testRequest.response.getContentAsString();

BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(httpResponse.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
ImageIO.write(imag, "png", new File(dirName,"snap.jpg"));
```

I am getting response properly. when i tried to convert it into buffered image.It's coming as null .

Raw Response looks something like this

HTTP/1.1 200 
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 26 Sep 2016 03:00:57 GMT
Content-Type: image/png;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-RateLimit-Limit: 15
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 14
X-RateLimit-Reset: 0

‰PNG.....special characters

Any helps appreciated.

Comment: Is image part of response or attachment?

Comment: Can you show raw response please?